Quotient space of $S^1\times \mathbb{C}P^4$
I am interested in the quotient spaces of $S^1\times \mathbb{C}P^4$ by relation
$(\zeta,[z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4])\sim(-\zeta,[\bar{z}_0,-i\bar{z}_1,\bar{z}_2,-i\bar{z}_3,\bar{z}_4])$
and relation
$(\zeta,[z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4])\sim(-\zeta,[-z_0,z_1,-z_2,z_3,-z_4])$.
I need to find their cohomological rings?
Are these any known spaces?
My gut feeling is lens spaces and $\bar{\mathbb{C}P^4}$.

This looks like a quotient by a finite group action. So the quotient can't be $\overline{{\Bbb CP}^4}$. The quotient will have the same dimensions as $S^1 \times {\Bbb CP}^4$.
